# most efficient way to loop every second in javascript

Tags: loops, react-native, setinterval, react-native-ios

I am displaying different images every second infinitely in a loop.

Is there any efficient way (other than `setInterval`) to run a particular block of code every second without freezing the app or ruining the performance of it.

Comment: Whats wrong with setInterval like?

Comment: Nothing Sir, actually. Looking to learn another way to loop instead of using an inbuilt event, might even help in learning how setInterval too is working, just curious